# making the value of my button as a variable

Tags: javascript, button

I thought this would be easy and I've googled it a bit but couldn't find how to do it.

I have:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>

var string1 = "pigs"
document.write(string1)

</script>

</head>
<body>

<input type = "button" value="string1" id="button">
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get the value of the button to say 'pigs'? I tried:

value=string1

value = document.write(string1)

value = "document.write(string1)"

but no luck, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use : **[document.getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp)**

```
document.getElementById("button").value = string1;
```

What you have used is document.write:

```
The write() method writes HTML expressions or JavaScript code to a document.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get the button first before you can assign a value to it.

```
document.querySelector("#button").value = string1;
```

Comment: Both correct, yet I can only accept one answer :( I'm just more used to getElementById....